# how do you get a list of waypoints assuming that there is a map

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ros, waypoint

I'm a beginner learning ROS. I'm developing an android application that will control my robot and that includes getting the list of waypoints to display it to my spinner. just wanted to ask on how do you get the list of waypoints assuming that there is a map

I've already done the code for subscribing to the topic /waypoints and serializing its msg type

so this is my code for serializing the msg-type of the topic /waypoints:

```
public class WaypointList {

    @SerializedName("waypoints")
    @Expose
    public List<WaypointList> waypoints = null;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public WaypointList() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param waypoints
     */
    public WaypointList(List<WaypointList> waypoints) {
        super();
        this.waypoints = waypoints;
    }
}
```

I expect that the data of the topic /waypoints will be displayed to my spinner

Comment: You are making a list of waypoint list but what is a waypoint for you ? Where does it come from ?

Comment: @Ben-J my list of waypoints is in the topic /waypoints. i needed a variable that will hold all the data inside the topic /waypoints that will match the data to my serialized message type which is the codes above to be able to display the list to my spinner.

Comment: @Ben-J basically its just a waypoints inside the topic assuming that there is a map. i just need the list of waypoints with or without the source of its map